# Angular concat array

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular controller, i loop through an array of cities to retrieve each value sent :

```
angular.forEach($scope.outPutcities, function (value, key) {
// value.id are 3,4          
   $scope.countries.cityId = value.id;
   $scope.cities.push($scope.countries.cityId)   
});
```

But the cityId value has always the last value in the array which is 4.

```
[Object { countryName=Canada,  cityId=**4**}, Object {countryName=Canada,  cityId=**4**]
```

But what i want is :

```
 [Object { countryName=Canada,  cityId=**3**}, Object {countryName=Canada,  cityId=**4**]
```

Is there an easy to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, Please could you put how you are writing `$scope.countries` and `$scope.cities`.

Comment: You're rewriting to the same reference of country for each item in the enumeration done by `forEach`.  Try the following for the last line: `$scope.cities.push({ countryName: $scope.countries.countryName, cityId: value.id})`

Comment: Hi mtadd. I knew i was creating the same reference of the country in my loop, but i just didn't know how to put the right json format inside the push function. Now you showed my how and this is what i was looking for. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is redundant

```
$scope.countries.cityId = value.id;
```

You are assigning to countries.cityId and overwriting it on each iteration, rather just do

```
$scope.cities.push(value.id)
```

Your code does look fine besides that, are you sure the $scope.outPutcities has the values you are expecting?

Comment: The following code is not redundant : $scope.countries.cityId = value.id; because i want to have this output  [Object { countryName=Canada,  cityId=3}, Object {countryName=Canada,  cityId=4]. If i only put $scope.cities.push(value.id), my json output will be this : ["3","4"] which not the result expected. $scope.countries it's my model that i load and that containt the attributes : countryName and cityId